# Is there a reference for the numerical schemes used to describe the convection terms?

Tags: fipy

I just found the numerical schemes for describing the convective terms, which are used in FiPy (https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/numerical/scheme.html).

I am currently implementing similar schemes for solving convective problems. I would like to investigate the performance of these schemes compared to those, which are presented here.

Is there a reference, where I can read more about the presented schemes?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The FiPy docs do have a few [references](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/references.html) that are relevant, see [15](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/references.html#croftphd), [20](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/references.html#patankar) and [21](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/references.html#versteegmalalasekera), in particular. The link for [15](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/references.html#croftphd) is broken, but I found a copy of the thesis [here](https://gala.gre.ac.uk/id/eprint/6371/1/Croft_-DX233093_COMPLETED.pdf). These mostly only cover the first order schemes.

If you're looking into higher order schemes that aren't implemented in FiPy then you might want to look at [volume 2 of Hirsch](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112091212240) and [Leveque](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253). [Leveque](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253) is good if you want to understand how coupled systems of hyperbolic equations are implemented correctly. [CLAWPACK](https://www.clawpack.org/) is the code based on the [Leveque](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253) book. It is another option to compare against if you're implementing higher order convection schemes.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick response! The references were really helpful.